# Reduce array to object using arrow function

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, arrow-functions

I'm playing around with the limits of array and arrow functions and I'm trying to convert this reduce function into an arrow function:

```
var monthsById = months.reduce(function(result, month) {
                            result[month.Id] = month;
                            return result;
                        }, {});
```

But I'm having trouble to return the map, since `result[month.Id] = month;` will return the month and not the map like in this approach:

```
var monthsById = months.reduce((byId, month) => byId[month.Id] = month, {});
```

So I'm looking for a single statement, that sets the value AND returns the object. (`new Map()` is not an option, since I need it in the regular `{}` format).

```js
var months = [ { Id: 1 }, { Id: 2 }, { Id: 3 } ];

var monthsById = months.reduce((byId, month) => byId[month.Id] = month, {});

console.log(monthsById);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can return `byId` in each iteration and wrap function body in parentheses `()`

```js
var months = [ { Id: 1 }, { Id: 2 }, { Id: 3 } ];

var monthsById = months.reduce((byId, month) => (byId[month.Id] = month, byId), {});
console.log(monthsById);
```

Comment: Wow! Exactly what I was looking for, I knew there are no limits :D may you add a reference what => (a, b) does? I don't fully understand it yet.

Comment: It will return last `expression` inside `()` in this case its accumulator parameter in reduce or `byId`

Comment: @Basti it's comma operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) where you set a new property with [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) and return the whole object.

```js
var months = [{ Id: 1 }, { Id: 2 }, { Id: 3 }],
    monthsById = months.reduce((byId, month) => Object.assign(byId, { [month.Id]: month }), {});

console.log(monthsById);
```

An example with spreading.

```js
var months = [{ Id: 1 }, { Id: 2 }, { Id: 3 }],
    monthsById = months.reduce((byId, month) => ({ ...byId, [month.Id]: month }), {});

console.log(monthsById);
```

Comment: great! I thought of something like this, but didn't know how to assign the dynamic key :)

Comment: Thanks! You already received my +1 before ;) (And even [posted](https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6695466615036809216/) about it).