# Create object while looping through an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to create an object using the values of items inside an array.

```
const arrOfObj = [
{city: 'Tokyo', country: 'Japan', ...other values},
{city: 'Paris', country: 'France', ...other values}, 
{city: 'London', country: 'UK', ...other values}, 
{city: 'New York', country: 'USA', ...other values}
]
```

expected object:

```
const obj = {
Japan: 'Tokyo', 
France: 'Paris', 
UK: 'London', 
USA: 'New York'
}
```

Can you guys have any suggestion to achieve this in an efficient way? All the comments will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: "I am trying to create an object" - care to show us how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reduce array to object using arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49209046/reduce-array-to-object-using-arrow-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) can be used :

```js
const arrOfObj = [
  { city: 'Tokyo'   , country: 'Japan'  },
  { city: 'Paris'   , country: 'France' }, 
  { city: 'London'  , country: 'UK'     }, 
  { city: 'New York', country: 'USA'    }
]

const obj = Object.fromEntries( arrOfObj.map(o => [o.country, o.city]) )

console.log( obj )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the array and use the 'country' value as the property and set the value to the value of 'city'.

```
   const arrOfObj = [
    {city: 'Tokyo', countryL: 'Japan'},
    {city: 'Paris', countryL: 'France'}, 
    {city: 'London', countryL: 'UK'}, 
    {city: 'New York', countryL: 'USA'}
    ]

    let obj = {};
    arrOfObj.forEach(o => {obj[o.countryL] = o.city});

    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```js
arrOfObj.reduce((acc, { city, country }) => {
  acc[country] = city
  return acc
}, {})
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: Try to explain your solution when you post an answer